# Ubuntu gnome 17.04 gdm login change monitor / screen

Tags: nvidia, gnome, login, multiple-monitors, display

I have two monitors. The greeter is displayed on the secondary monitor and I would like to change that.

I tried removing the secondary monitor's cable from the GPU and starting PC to force only one monitor to switch to primary and it worked, but after that I returned the cable for the second monitor and powered on the PC with two monitors and the login screen is still on the secondary monitor.

I tried disabling the monitor in **Display Settings**, but during login it is turned on.

Comment: What happens if you swap the video monitor cables at the video card ports?

Comment: On Nvidia 1060 GPU i have 1 DVI-D (secondary monitor), 3 Display Ports (Primary), 1 HDMI (TV) (Not using it or a problem), so i can not connect DVI-D or VGA to Display port.

Comment: In the Nvidia utilities, isn't there an option to set up the "primary" monitor?

Comment: Yes, its checked also in Gnome Displays, if system goes on sleep / stand by, the login screen is on primary monitor.

Comment: Now you lost me. I thought that the problem was that the login screen was appearing on the secondary monitor.

Comment: It does appear on boot, but on stand by/ sleep it does not

Comment: After update from 17.04 to 17.10 and several system updates it is working as intended, login monitor is set by arranging them in settings.